# Creating a N:1 Relationship on Order Product Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a N:1 relationship off another entity to Order Product.  It is not an option in the pick list.  I then tried to go to Order Product and create a 1:N relationship and it also does not allow it.

I am sure this is by design from Microsoft, but is there a way to achive this?  I perfer not to to a 1:N or N:N as a work around since it will create grids on the form (and that does not make much sense from a UI perspective when there will only be one record).

Thank for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add a single line of text field and format it as a url. Then link it to the related entity by dynamically populating a URL to the entity. It is a work around but of all the possible scenarios its the best for my situation

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem during building a solution for a client. It was a heavy restriction so in the end we just created our own order product entity and linked it via a one to many to order.

This gave us complete control over it and could add relationships as we wish.

This came at a cost unfortunately as you lose the auto calculation on order for example. This wasn't an issue however as we didn't need it or any of the price list functionality.

If this is an option for you I'd recommend doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that everybody had to face the same problem in his CRM life.

For CRM, the entities, salesorderproduct... are entities used only to enumerate the products of the entity related in its name, and you can not do almost nothing, that's another problem with a workaround, that I'll try to explain, just to see if this could be the solution to creating relations with them, but I don't think so.

The problem is that you can not use the assign functionality as in other relations to copy data from one entityproduct to the lower-level entityproduct when you create custom fields, and you want to copy throught the entire workflow of sales section. In this case, there is no option to enter the "Assign" window (I use Assign because I have always worked in Spanish) and create the field mappings between them.

This could be done by searching the GUID of the "Assign" window, and copyign into any of the URLs of the "Assign" window, the window showed up, and you could do your custom mappings.

I hope this could help, although this question is too old, so I hope other that arrive here, could see more opinions :)

See you